# Imprimir Varios Datos con un Vector en C++

Tags: c++

Buenas Noches tengo el siguiente ejercicio en el que requiero que al final me imprima los datos (Nombre y Edad) de las personas de mas de 60 años.

Hasta los momentos no lo hace correctamente e imprime todos los casos y de paso la edad no es la indicada si no otros numeros. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int i = 0, cpersonas_tercera = 0, edad[2], edad_tercera[2];
float tercera_edad = 0, promedio;
char nombre[2][30];

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"< = = = D A T O S  P E R S O N A L E S = = = >";
    cout<<"\n\nNombre: ";
    cin>>nombre[i];
    cout<<"\nEdad: ";
    cin>>edad[i];

    if (edad[i] >= 60)
    {
        cpersonas_tercera++;
        tercera_edad = tercera_edad + edad[i];
    }
}

promedio = tercera_edad / cpersonas_tercera;

system("cls");
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
cout<<"< = = = D A T O S  R E C O L E C T A D O S = = = >";
cout<<"\n\nCantidad de Personas de Tercera Edad (+60 Años): "<<cpersonas_tercera;
cout<<"\n\nPromedio de la Tercera Edad (+60 Años): "<<promedio;

for (i = 1 ; i <= 2 ; i++)
{
    if (edad[i] >= 60)
    {
        cout<<"\nNombre: "<<nombre[i];
        cout<<"\nEdad: "<<edad[i];
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: su codigo muestra lo que comenta o muestra lo que yo entiendo que quiere mostrar test ideonline, *quizas esta ejecutando una version antigua del ejecutable*. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu principal error esta en ambos bucles, estos empiezan en la posición 1 hasta la 2. Al declarar el array edad[2], sí creas 2 espacios, el problema esta en que tienes que tener siempre en cuenta que los arrays empiezan desde la posición 0.

Ej:

```
edad[5]--> [0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
```

En el bucle comienzas desde la posición 1 que realmente sera la 2, por lo que al imprimir la posición 2 buscara una información que no existe.

## En resumen esto se soluciona cambiando:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
```